# 2 object of same type returns true when != checked

Tags: winforms, oop, c#-4.0

I am using model.GetType().GetProperties() with foreach to compare properties of 2 object of same class.
like this

```
 foreach (var item in kayit.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        var g = item.GetValue(plu);
                        var b = item.GetValue(kayit);
                        if (g is string && b is string&& g!=b)
                        {
                                a += item.Name + "*";

                        }
                        else if (g is DateTime&& b is DateTime&& g!=b)
                        {
                            a += item.Name + "*";
                        }


                    }
```

But the problem is even if they have the same value g!=b returns a true all the time. I have used a break point to prove this and they are literally same thing. Actually I am taking the value putting it in textbox then creating another class after button click and comaring to see the changed properties. So even if I don't change anything it doesn't read the mas equals. Can someone help me about this please?

more info:
I get the plu from database and populate my control with it:

```
            txtorder.Text = plu.OrderNo;
            dtporder.Value = nulldate(plu.OrderDate);            
            dtp1fit.Value = nulldate(plu.FirstFitDate);
            dtp1yorum.Value = nulldate(plu.FirstCritDate);
            dtp2fit.Value = nulldate(plu.SecondFitDate);
            dtp2yorum.Value = nulldate(plu.SecondCritDate);
            dtpsizeset.Value = nulldate(plu.SizeSetDate);
            dtpsizesetok.Value = nulldate(plu.SizeSetOkDate);
            dtpkumasplan.Value = nulldate(plu.FabricOrderByPlan);
            txtTedarikci.Text = plu.Fabric_Supplier;
            dtpkumasFP.Value = nulldate(plu.FabricOrderByFD);
            dtpfabarrive.Value = nulldate(plu.FabricArrive);
            dtpbulk.Value = nulldate(plu.BulkFabricDate);
            dtpbulkok.Value = nulldate(plu.BulkConfirmDate);
            dtpaccessory.Value = nulldate(plu.AccessoriesDate);
            dtpaccessoryarrive.Value = nulldate(plu.AccessoriesArriveDate);
            dtpcutok.Value = nulldate(plu.ProductionStartConfirmation);
            dtpcutstart.Value = nulldate(plu.ProductionStart);
            dtpshipmentdate.Value = nulldate(plu.ShipmentDate);
            dtpshipmentsample.Value = nulldate(plu.ShipmentSampleDate);
            dtpshippedon.Value = nulldate(plu.Shippedon);
```

nulldate is just a method where I change null values to my default value.
And this is what I do after button click:

```
 var kayit = new uretim();
  kayit.OrderNo = txtorder.Text.ToUpper();
                kayit.OrderDate = vdat(dtporder.Value);
                kayit.FirstFitDate = vdat(dtp1fit.Value);
                kayit.FirstCritDate = vdat(dtp1yorum.Value);
                kayit.SecondFitDate = vdat(dtp2fit.Value);
                kayit.SecondCritDate = vdat(dtp2yorum.Value);
                kayit.SizeSetDate = vdat(dtpsizeset.Value);
                kayit.SizeSetOkDate = vdat(dtpsizesetok.Value);
                kayit.FabricOrderByPlan = vdat(dtpkumasplan.Value);
                kayit.Fabric_Supplier = txtTedarikci.Text;
                kayit.FabricOrderByFD = vdat(dtpkumasFP.Value);
                kayit.FabricArrive = vdat(dtpfabarrive.Value);
                kayit.BulkFabricDate = vdat(dtpbulk.Value);
                kayit.BulkConfirmDate = vdat(dtpbulkok.Value);
                kayit.AccessoriesDate = vdat(dtpaccessory.Value);
                kayit.AccessoriesArriveDate = vdat(dtpaccessoryarrive.Value);
                kayit.ProductionStartConfirmation = vdat(dtpcutok.Value);
                kayit.ProductionStart = vdat(dtpcutstart.Value);
                kayit.ShipmentDate = vdat(dtpshipmentdate.Value);
                kayit.ShipmentSampleDate = vdat(dtpshipmentsample.Value);
                kayit.Shippedon = vdat(dtpshippedon.Value);
                kayit.Status = true;
                kayit.WrittenDate = DateTime.Now;
                kayit.GuidKey = plu.GuidKey != null ? plu.GuidKey : Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

I have proven by breakpoint that values are actually same. But the != check retruns a true.

Comment: Can you please add more complete code.. May be you think you are comparing g and b by value but it’s doing it by reference or vice versa.. Checkout boxing and unboxing and avoid it inside loops..

Comment: More info added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing

```
g != b
```

compiler doesn't know that these objects are strings to compare so it compares their references. You can do:

```
g.Equals(b) //be carefull if one of them is null
```

or

```
g.ToString() != b.ToString()
```

**EDIT**

You can compare them after you check the type:

```
if (g is string && b is string)
{
    if( g.ToString() != b.ToString() ){

    }                    

}
```

Comment: Would it be solved If I cast them? Since it is not just string and can be null I can't use your examples.